# Is there a way to pass parameter outside of map function - ReactJS - Typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

At the moment i get from the Back End an array of objects that looks like this :

```
const myArr = [ 
   { 
    A: "Ananas", 
    B: "Banana", 
    C: "Citroen"
   }
]
```

I want to display a single JSX select menu per row with the options from the Array `Ananas , Banana , Citroen` . That's why I am using this method:

```
<Select onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}>
   {myArr [0] &&
    Object.entries(myArr [0]).map(([key, value]) => (
     <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>
   ))}
</Select>
```

But the thing is that in order to keep the good JSX structure I have to keep the `Select` outside of my `.map()` function otherwise I will have many menus if it is inside.

My ultimate goal is to pass the `key` parameter from the `.map()` function back to the `Select`.

```
<Select name={key} onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}>
```

**EDIT** :
So behind the scenes it will look like :

```
<Select name="A"> 
  <MenuItem value="Ananas">Ananas</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Banana">Banana</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Citroen">Citroen</MenuItem>
</Select>

<Select name="B"> 
  <MenuItem value="Ananas">Ananas</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Banana">Banana</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Citroen">Citroen</MenuItem>
</Select>

<Select name="C"> 
  <MenuItem value="Ananas">Ananas</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Banana">Banana</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="Citroen">Citroen</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

**EDIT 2.0** :
If we wrap everything into one loop so that we can have access to everything like this :

```
   { myArr [0] &&
      Object.entries(myArr [0]).map(([key, value]) => (
       <Select name ={key} onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}>
         <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>
       </Select>
   ))}
```

The render result is looking like this :
[image]

And this is something that we defenately do not want to see

I do not know if this is possible, but still I prefer to ask. I hope there is someone that can give me an inside of the issue or at least a way to fix my issue. Huge thanks!

Comment: But there are *multiple* `key` values resulting from the iteration. Which one specifically you want to use? First one? Last one? Something else?

Comment: What is the problem, or use case, you are trying to solve for? What you ask doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @VLAZ  @Drew Reese i need to apply the `key` value of `A, B, C` as `name` on the `Select` component . But the problem is the `Select` has to live outside of the `.map()` function

Comment: @PandaMastr so you need `<Select name="A, B, C"`? If so, why not `<Select name={Object.keys(myArr [0]).join(", ")}`?

Comment: @PandaMastr do you have property "A", "B", and "C" stored in your state and you want to save your selected value in those properties?

Comment: @VLAZ i've done an edit so you can see a preview what the initial idea is .

Comment: So, you need one `<Select>` for each menu item and then all of the menu items in each select? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes on each row i need one `<Select>` but this select has to contain the value of the `<MenuItem>` as `Ananas , Banana , Citroen` .

Comment: @PandaMastr What's preventing you from running the same loop, you use to render the menu items, around the outer select? Thereby getting access to the key, which you could then pass to the select component? Though, for better semantics, you might want to use `Object.keys` for the outer, and `Object.values` for the inner loop.

Comment: @Yoshi Can you give an example ? I tried wrapping everything into one loop so that i have access to everything, but the render does not agree and shows multiple select menu's ( This is not the idea )

Comment: Now I'm confused?! In your question you show multiple select menus, and now you don't want them?

Comment: @Yoshi i have done another edit . Maybe it will be more clear for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235211/discussion-between-yoshi-and-pandamastr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need a nested `map()`. One on the `Object.keys()` to create the select elements and one on the `Object.values()` to populate each select.

The snippet below achieves this using `Object.entries()` and passing the `entries` array on to the inner `map()`.

```
const myArr = [ 
   { 
    A: "Ananas", 
    B: "Banana", 
    C: "Citroen"
   }
]

{
  myArr[0] && Object.entries(myArr[0]).map(([key], _, entries) => (
    <Select key={key} name={key}>
      {entries.map(([, value]) => (
        <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>)
      )
      }
    </Select>)
  )
}
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const myArr = [{ A: "Ananas", B: "Banana", C: "Citroen" }];

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(`${e.target.name}: ${e.target.value}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {myArr[0] && Object.entries(myArr[0]).map(([key], _, entries) => (
        <select key={key} name={key} onChange={handleChange}>
          {entries.map(([, value]) => (
            <option value={value}>{value}</option>)
          )
          }
        </select>)
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is also a solution . Thanks mate ! I have tested it out , but mine works also . So i will leave it both for future reference for someone if need them

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion from @Yoshi this is the correct following answer to my problem. Because i am importing my static row names from another file like this :

**textDisplay.js**

```
 export default [
       {
         label: 'Fruits',
         required: true,
       },

       {
        label: 'Fruits 2',
        required: true,
       },

       {
       label: 'Fruits 3',
       required: true,
       },
    ]
```

So that i can have a structure to display like the following picture :
[image]

@Yoshi
Here's the idea: When we map over textDisplay with: textDisplay.map((column, i) => (...) we have an index i, this will be 0, 1, 2. What we need to do is, get the correct key from myArr by using that index.

```
 // importing our text data to display 
    import textDisplay '../../textDisplay.js'
    const foo = () => {
      // incoming data
      const myArr = [
        {
          A: "Ananas",
          B: "Banana",
          C: "Citroen"
        }
      ];
    
      const items = myArr[0];
      const keys = Object.keys(items);
      const values = Object.values(items);
    
      return (
        <List>
          {textDisplay.map((column, i) => (
            <ListItem key={column.keyValue}>
              <ListItemText>
                {column.label} {column.required ? '*' : ''}
              </ListItemText>
              <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <Select name={keys[i]} onChange={(e: any, id) => handleChange(e, id)}>
                  {values.map(value => (
                    <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      );
    };
```